# Spectrum is ringed space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, ringed-spaces

Hello I just started studying theory about affine schemes and I am now studying ringed spaces. I see everywhere the Spec(R) is a ringed space but I can’t find a proof. I think it’s obvious since the structure sheaf of spectrum has a construction of sheaf but is this enough for a proof? Do you know any books to suggest me for studying this topic in general?

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEt-PSmc3-AhX3gP0HHd_pAC4QtwJ6BAgIEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DAYDq0qY34HU&usg=AOvVaw0YaIkn_o-6t463Tu5N5uAc) for a proof.